# Java ssh connection in Windows and Linux

Tags: java, linux, ssh, jsch, openssh

I'm trying to connect to SSH with a Java application, but I'm not having much success because it gives an unexpected error. My application is running on a Windows computer but I am trying to connect to a Fedora 29 linux server. Import information merely changed. And by the way, I do not just need the connection, but also that this code executes commands on that terminal.

I already got the connection but it gives an error on line 22 .

```
"package teste;

import com.jcraft.jsch.*; 
import java.io.InputStream; 
import java.io.InputStreamReader; 
import java.util.Scanner;

public class SSHReadFile { public static void main(String args[]) { String user = "root";
 String password = "xxxxxxx"; 
 String host = "000.000.000.000"; 
 int port = 22; 
 String remoteFile = "/home";
 try { JSch jsch = new JSch();
    com.jcraft.jsch.Session session = jsch.getSession(user, host, port);
 session.setPassword(password); 
 session.setConfig("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no"); 
 System.out.println("Establishing Connection..."); 
 session.connect(); System.out.println("Connection established.");
 System.out.println("Crating SFTP Channel."); 
 Channel sftpChannel = session.openChannel("sftp"); 
 sftpChannel.connect(); 
 System.out.println("SFTP Channel created."); 
 InputStream inputStream = sftpChannel.get("/home"); 
 try (Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new InputStreamReader(inputStream))) { while (scanner.hasNextLine()) { String line = scanner.nextLine(); 
 System.out.println(line); } } } catch (JSchException e) { } 
 } 

    public class Session {

        public Session() {
        }

        public void setConfig(String strictHostKeyChecking, String no) {
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
        }

        public void setPassword(String password) {
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
        }
    }

    public class ChannelSftp {

        public ChannelSftp() {
        }

        public void connect() {
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
        }

        public InputStream get(String remoteFile) {
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
        }
    }
 }"
```

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Uncompilable source code - Erroneous sym type: com.jcraft.jsch.Channel.get
    at teste_ls.SSHReadFile.main(SSHReadFile.java:22)

Comment: Isn't the problem that you're trying to fetch a directory as a stream? You should be calling sftpChannel.ls to list a directory

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Channel sftpChannel = session.openChannel("sftp"); 
...
InputStream inputStream = sftpChannel.get("/home");
```

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Uncompilable source code - Erroneous sym type: com.jcraft.jsch.Channel.get at teste_ls.SSHReadFile.main(SSHReadFile.java:22)

Your immediate problem is that you've declared the variable `sftpChannel` as a plain [`Channel`](https://epaul.github.io/jsch-documentation/javadoc/com/jcraft/jsch/Channel.html) instead of a [`ChannelSftp`](https://epaul.github.io/jsch-documentation/javadoc/com/jcraft/jsch/ChannelSftp.html). So you can only call methods which are defined by the `Channel` class. `Channel` does not have a method named `get()`, so you get a compiler error.

You want to call `ChannelSftp.get()`, so you should define the variable as a `ChannelSftp`:

```
ChannelSftp sftpChannel = (ChannelSftp) session.openChannel("sftp"); 
...
InputStream inputStream = sftpChannel.get("/home");
```

The next problem you're likely to run into is that "/home" is probably a directory, and I don't think you can get a directory as an input stream. If you're trying to get a list of files in the directory, call [`SftpChannel.ls()`](https://epaul.github.io/jsch-documentation/javadoc/com/jcraft/jsch/ChannelSftp.html#ls-java.lang.String-):

```
for (LsEntry entry : (Vector<LsEntry>) SftpChannel.ls("/home")) {
    System.out.println(entry.getFilename());
    ...
}
```